# Does the sequence $\{\sin^n(n)\}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, diophantine-approximation

Does the sequence $\{\sin^n(n)\}$ converge?

Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sin^n(n)$ converge?

Comment: The sum doesn't exist since at $n=0$ you have: $\sin^n(n)=(\sin(0))^0=0^0.
$
Perhaps you mean? $\sum_{n=\color{red}1}^\infty \sin^n(n)$

Comment: A meaningless oversight. I'll fix it so the sum starts at 1, if you insist. But regardless, it is established by convention in mathematics that $0^0 = 1$.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%5E0

Comment: Also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form

Comment: @rajb245 Sigh. It's true that $0^0$ is left undefined in general (for good reasons), but in many contexts (also for good reasons!) the convention is to interpret $0^0$ as $1$. One of these contexts is indexed sums, as in the original question, whose meaning was completely unambiguous.

Answer (score 20):

claim.  The series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sin^n(n)$ diverges.

**Lemma.** For all number $x$ irrational there exist a rational sequence $\{\frac{p_n}{q_n}\}$ where $\{q_n\}$ is odd such that 
$$
\left\vert x-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right\vert<\frac{1}{q_n^2}
$$

*[Proof.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_%28number_theory%29)*

Define $x_n=\frac{1}{x_{n-1}-\lfloor x_{n-1}\rfloor}$. Let $a_0=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $a_n=\lfloor x_n\rfloor$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $R_n=a_0+\frac{1\vert}{\vert a_1}+\cdots+\frac{1\vert}{a_n\vert}$ wich denotes [continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction)

We have $x_{n+1}=a_{n+1}+\frac{1}{x_{n+2}}>a_{n+1}$ then we obtain that $$(q_n x_{n+1}+q_{n-1})q_n>(q_n a_{n+1}+q_{n-1})q_n=q_{n+1}q_n.$$

Then using an another result : $$\left\vert x-R_n\right\vert <\frac{1}{q_nq_{n+1}}$$
As $q_{n+1}=q_n a_{n+1}+q_{n-1}>q_na_{n+1}>q_n$
One can prove that the sequence $(q_n)$ contains an infinite odd number.

Indeed we have $$p_{k-1}q_k-q_{k-1}p_k=(-1)^k$$ for $k=1,2,\cdots,n$ and  use [Bézout's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem).

For a general result look at : [Irrationality Measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html)

Using the lemma for $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have $\vert \sin(p_n)\vert=\vert \cos (\frac{\pi}{2}q_n -p_n)\vert>\cos (\frac{1}{q_n})>1-\frac{1}{2q_n^2}$ then the sequence $\{(\sin(p_n)^{p_n}\}$ does not converges to $0$. $\square$

Comment: For the lemma (well-knonw to those who know it) cf. e.g. [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html).

Comment: For the conclusion about $\sin^n$, you may add that for almost all $n$, $(1-\frac1{2q_n^2})^{p_n}>(1-\frac1{p_n})^{p_n}\to\frac 1e$. And of course on the otherhand there are $n$ that are close to multiples of $\pi$, hance making $\sin^n n\approx 0$ for these so that ultimately $\sin^nn$ diverges.