# Series with non-negative terms: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\cos n|^n}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{|\cos n|^n}{n}$$

(being a series with non-negative terms), does it converge or diverge?

Unfortunately, I can't prove in any way or convergence or divergence of this series. Any ideas?

Comment: With $7000$ terms it's ( numerically ) $\approx 1.6\color{#f00}{666683043389468266458468225848077445946578253126}$. It's slightly larger than ${\pi^{2} \over 6} \approx 1.6449340668482264364724151666460251892189499012068$. Maybe, a nice question is to prove that the series is $> {\pi^{2} \over 6}$.

Answer (score 0):

The series' convergence is famously unknown. Specifically, see [this Mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/65873/32499) about the similar series with $\sin n$ instead of $\cos n$:

> For an interesting example, take $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin(n)|^n}{n}$.
>   Deciding whether or not this converges seems to require more knowledge than is currently available about the rational approximations of $\pi$.  The series
>   $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin(n t \pi)|^n}{n}$ converges for almost every 
>   real $t$ (in the sense of Lebesgue measure), but diverges for $t$ in a dense $G_\delta$ subset of $\mathbb R$.

Deciding whether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\cos(n)|^n}{n}$ converges, you will run into all of the same problems as with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin(n)|^n}{n}$.

Comment: Actually, $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{|\sin n|^n}{n}$ is convergent (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823816/is-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-sin-nnn-convergent/836054#836054) and the linked answer also spawned some research for efficient methods for its numerical computation.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Holy shit, so you solved an open series problem in a math stackexchange post? Then you should comment on Robert Israel's mathoverflow post...and do you have a link to a paper where this has been peer-reviewed?

Comment: actually I did not know it was an open problem, when I solved it here, so the only peer review actually made is by the MSE community. Anyway, I guess I will notify Robert about that, thanks for the suggestion.