# Is there a way to calculate $ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\sin({2^kx})$?

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

The context for this question is basic curiosity.  I know that there are formulas for calculating $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}\sin({kx})$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}\sin({2kx})$.  Is there a formula/method/identity that could be used to find
$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}\sin({2^kx})$ ?

Comment: Possible route to a solution: write $\sin(kx) = \frac{e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx}}{2i}$, then as there are finite sums you can split $\sum_i A_i-B_i = \sum_i A_i-\sum_i B_i$.  Then you just need to be able to evaluate $\sum_{i = 1}^n e^{i2^k x}$. If it were geometric (like for $\sin(kx)$, it'd be trivial).

Comment: Don't remember a formula for $\sum_{k=0}^n z^{2^k}$ offhand.

Comment: Short answer: no. Otherwise, this question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976417/a-community-project-prove-or-disprove-that-sum-n-geq-1-frac-sin2nn) would be simple to deal with.

Comment: To prove an inequality like $$\sum_{k=0}^{N}\sin(2^k x) \ll\frac{N}{\log\log N},$$ that is just a little stronger than the trivial bound $\ll N$, just for some values of $x$, would have deep consequences.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio - I take it your statement excludes obvious values of x?  There are infinite numbers for which $\sum_{k=0}^{N}\sin(2^k x)$ converges.  Namely any number that can be represented as ${\frac{a\pi}{2^b}}$ | a and b are any integers. The convergent value being strictly less than $\log(2b) = b$.  Thus $\sum_{k=0}^{N}\sin(2^k x) \ll b$ for these values of x.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio - In addition, any number that **cannot** be expressed as ${\frac{a\pi}{2^b}}$ can be approximated (to an arbitrary accuracy) by a number that **can** be expressed as ${\frac{a\pi}{2^b}}$. For example, ${\frac{\pi}{3}}$ can be approximated as ${\frac{21,845\pi}{2^{16}}}$.  These are the same number to the ten thousandths decimal place.  Hope this is helpful in some way.