# Calculate $\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(2^k x)$ using trigonometric identities

Tags: trigonometry, summation

As the title says, I'm trying to calculate $$\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(2^k x)$$ but I'm having some troubles since I haven't done trigonometry in a looong time. Can someone help me calculate it?

Comment: Try a couple terms first, the answer should become clearer. The double angle formulas are $\sin{2x}=2\sin{x}cos{x}$ and $\cos{2x}=\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}$

Comment: If you consider the natural frame of trigonometry is complex numbers, it's much simpler with the complex exponential.

Comment: [Check this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998177/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-displaystyle-sum-k-0n-sin2kx).

Comment: There is no reason for expecting that such sum has a nice closed form for general $n$s and $x$s. It is not even clear if such sum is $o(n)$ as $n\to +\infty$.