# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2^n)}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2^n)}{n} $$
converge?

Based on [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), series like $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(a[n])}{n} $$ converges when $a[n]$ is an arithmetic sequence. Different from this case, where $2^n$ is a geometric sequence. Not clear if Dirichet's test is still applicable.

Comment: This is indeed a very hard problem. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976417/a-community-project-prove-or-disprove-that-sum-n-geq-1-frac-sin2nn)

Comment: As far as I understand it : It is not hard to define a sequence $c_n$ such that the convergence of $\sum_n c_n$ is equivalent to an unproven conjecture, or even to an undecidable problem. What is intriguing here is that $\sum_n \frac{\sin(2^n)}{n}$ is easy to define and doesn't seem directly related to a known problem (in contrary to things like $\sum_n \frac{n^{-a}}{\sin(n)}$ depending on the irrationality measure of $\pi$)