# Convergence of a series involving $\sin(n)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

How does one determine whether or not the infinite series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin^n(n)$$
converges? I suspect that it doesn't converge absolutely, but I have no idea how to prove/disprove convergence or prove/disprove absolute convergence. Help?

Comment: I just feel like sharing this wonderful, somewhat related solution/problem:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282259/is-the-series-sum-n-sin-nn-n-convergent/282290#282290

Comment: Does the general term go to zero?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is negative. Quoting the first part of the answer I gave to [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823816/is-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-sin-nnn-convergent),

> The irrational number $\frac{\pi}{2}$ has an infinite number of convergents $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ with an odd denominator, hence $\left|\frac{p_n}{q_n}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right|\leq\frac{1}{q_n^2}$ gives:
> $$ \left|\sin(p_n)\right| = \left|\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}q_n+\frac{\theta}{q_n}\right)\right|=\left|\cos\frac{\theta}{q_n}\right|,\quad |\theta|\leq 1,$$
> $$ \left|\sin(p_n)\right|\geq 1-\frac{1}{q_n^2}$$
> hence $\left|\sin n\right|^n$ is bigger that $\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n$ infinitely often.

In particular the main term of the given series *does not* converge to zero, so such series is not convergent (either conditionally or absolutely).