# Convergence of $(\sin x)^x$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

This showed up on a forum and had no clear answer so I'm asking this here to see if anyone can give some light.

Define the sequence $$a_n := (\sin n)^n \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

How do you proof the existence of $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$?
Thanks.

Comment: I'd guess that there is a constant $q<1$ such that $|\sin n|<q$ for all $n$, since sine is equal to $\pm 1$ on multiples of $\pi$. Then it follows by squeeze theorem.

Comment: @Sisyphus There is none because $\sin(\mathbb{N})$ is dense in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Maybe you can find some help [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665776/convergence-of-the-sequence-frac1n-sinn)

Comment: Your title is misleading. $(\sin x)^x$ does not converge.

Comment: I believe my answer is complete now. Would you check it out please?

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811717/does-the-sequence-sinnn-converge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer: It does not converge to anything! It must be clear that this does not converge to any non-zero $L$. So the question is: "Does it converge to zero."
Let the proposition $P$, be the "converges to zero!" statement. Then
$$P^c="\exists\varepsilon>0 \textrm{ s.t. } \#\{n\in\mathbb{N}\Big||\sin n|>\varepsilon^\frac{1}{n}\}=\infty"$$
But using the approximation
$\varepsilon^\frac{1}{n}\approx\frac{-\log\varepsilon}{n}$ This becomes
$$P^c="\exists a<\infty \textrm{ s.t. } \#\{n\in\mathbb{N}\Big||\sin n|>1-\frac{a}{n}\}=\infty"$$
Then it is easy to use the properties of the sine function to see that
$$P^c=Q_-\cup Q_+$$
With
$$Q_\pm="\#\Big\{n\in\mathbb{N}\Big||\{\frac{n}{2\pi}\mp\frac{1}{4}\}|<\frac{a}{\sqrt n}\Big\}=\infty"$$
From now on we focus only on the proposition $Q_+$ and try to prove it. Let $A$ be the conjecture

$A$: For any sequence $0\leq e_n\leq 1$ with infinite sum $\sum_0^\infty e_n$, any irrational number $\alpha\in(0,1)$ and any sequence $t_n\in[0, 1]$ for which the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}t_n$ exists, the following holds

$$\#\Big\{(n, \{n\alpha\})\Big|n\in\mathbb{N}, |\{n\alpha\}-t_n|\leq e_n\Big\}=\infty$$

Then with $e_n=\min(1, \frac{a}{\sqrt n})$, $\alpha=\frac{1}{2\pi}$, $t_n=.25$ we get
$$A\Rightarrow Q_+\Rightarrow P^c$$
And

I believe $A$ holds. But to solve the recent problem it is easier to use Dirichlet's Approximation Theorem. It states that that for every irrational $\alpha\in(0,1)$ there is an infinite sequence $n_k$ for which $\{n_k\alpha\}\leq\frac{1}{n_k}$. Now consider the infinite sequence
$$m_k:=n_k\Big\lfloor\frac{1}{4\{n_k\alpha\}}\Big\rfloor$$
For this we have
$$m_k\{n_k\alpha\}^2=n_k\{n_k\alpha\}^2\Big\lfloor\frac{1}{4\{n_k\alpha\}}\Big\rfloor\leq.25n_k\{n_k\alpha\}\leq.25$$
Or equivalently
$$\{n_k\alpha\}\leq\frac{.5}{\sqrt{m_k}}$$
This guarantees
$$|\{m_k\alpha\}-.25|\leq\{n_k\alpha\}\leq\frac{.5}{\sqrt{m_k}}$$
Which proves $Q_+$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, this is what I was searching for!

Comment: Good, as good as your comment to my hasty and wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a long comment, not a full answer!**

Note that:
$$(\sin n)^n=\left(-i\sinh(-in)\right)^n=\frac{(-i)^n}{2^n}\left(e^{-in}-e^{in}\right)^n.$$
By the binomial expansion, we get:

$$\begin{align*}
s_n=(e^{-in}-e^{in})^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}e^{-ikn}(-1)^{n-k}e^{i(n-k)n}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}e^{in(n-2k)}.
\end{align*}$$

Consider the following cases:

- If $n$ is even, then, we have:
  $$s_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}e^{in(n-2k)}+\sum_{k=n/2+1}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}e^{in(n-2k)}.$$
  Let $l=n-k$ in the second sum:
  $$\sum_{k=n/2+1}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}e^{in(n-2k)}=\sum_{l=0}^{n/2-1}\binom{n}{n-l}(-1)^{n-l}e^{in(2l-n)}=\sum_{l=0}^{n/2-1}\binom{n}{l}(-1)^{l}e^{in(2l-n)}.$$
  So, we get:
  $$\begin{align*}s_n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}e^{in(n-2k)}+\sum_{l=0}^{n/2-1}\binom{n}{l}(-1)^{l}e^{in(2l-n)}=\\
  &=\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}e^{in(n-2k)}+\sum_{l=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{l}(-1)^{l}e^{in(2l-n)}-\binom{n}{n/2}(-1)^{n/2}=\\
  &=\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}\left(e^{in(n-2k)}+e^{in(2k-n)}\right)-\binom{n}{n/2}(-1)^{n/2}=\\
  &=2\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}\frac{e^{in(n-2k)}+e^{-in(n-2k)}}{2}-\binom{n}{n/2}(-1)^{n/2}=\\
  &=2\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}\cosh(in(n-2k))-\binom{n}{n/2}(-1)^{n/2}=\\
  &=2\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}\cos(n(n-2k))-\binom{n}{n/2}(-1)^{n/2}.
  \end{align*}$$
- If $n$ is odd, then, we have:
  $$s_n=\sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}e^{in(n-2k)}+\sum_{k=(n+1)/2}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}e^{in(n-2k)}.$$
  Let $l=n-k$ in the second sum:
  $$\sum_{k=n/2+1}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}e^{in(n-2k)}=\sum_{l=0}^{(n-1)/2}\binom{n}{n-l}(-1)^{n-l}e^{in(2l-n)}=\sum_{l=0}^{(n-1)/2}\binom{n}{l}(-1)^{l}e^{in(2l-n)}.$$
  So, we get:
  $$\begin{align*}s_n&=\sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}e^{in(n-2k)}+\sum_{l=0}^{(n-1)/2}\binom{n}{l}(-1)^{l}e^{in(2l-n)}=\\
  &=\sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}\left(e^{in(n-2k)}+e^{in(2k-n)}\right)=\\
  &=2\sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}\frac{e^{in(n-2k)}+e^{-in(n-2k)}}{2}=\\
  &=2\sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}\cosh(in(n-2k))=\\
  &=2\sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}\cos(n(n-2k)).
  \end{align*}$$

It remains to study this as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: This looks much much harder to do :))

Comment: Good insight thought, I will take it a carefully look later. Thanks both.

Comment: I think this could somehow be transformed into a quasi Legendre polynomial expression, however, I cannot see it right now.